# Eclipse imports github C project wrong. Why?

Tags: github, import, properties, eclipse-cdt, program-entry-point

I have a Problem with my Eclipse. I tried to import a github project. This also worked but i cant run this project. I think the issue has to do something with this properties(you see them in the pictures), but I have no idea how to solve my problem. I tried nearly everything.
Did I import something wrong?

[image: Thats how my project and the main looks like][image: I think the issue has to do something with this properties][image: I think the issue has to do something with this properties]

I realy would appreciate it, if somebody could help me. Thx

Comment: Where should Eclipse know how to import it (_"Hello World in C, Ansi-style"_ is just a comment and not more than a hint)? Does creating a C project, as you have already done, and copying the code into it, work?

Comment: yes this works.